# Error grouping MySQL query results together

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this message table that allows users to send messages to one another. `sender_id` is the id of the person who sent the message. `receiver_id` is the id of the person who received the message. `message_id` adds the `sender_id` and `receiver_id` together. This is a sample below.

```
               id   sender_id receiver_id message_id message time
               1        2         7          9         hi     -
               2        7         2          9         hello
               3        4         2          6         good
               4        2         4          6         bad
```

Now, I am trying to group the messages together using message_id by doing this.

Note: `$_SESSION['id'] is '2'`

```
$query = "SELECT *  FROM message WHERE sender_id = :id OR receiver_id = :id GROUP BY message_id HAVING COUNT(*) >=1 ORDER BY time DESC";
foreach ($db->query($query, array('id' => $_SESSION['id'])) AS $output)
               {
                $message = $output['message'];
               }
```

What displays is:

```
hi
good
```

But I want the query to show the latest messages and not the first messages i.e.

```
hello
bad
```

Please, how do I do this?

Comment: on what basis you are saying hi is first and hello is last is it sorted or something?

Comment: Yes. I wanted to sort it using GROUP BY

Comment: No Group by doesnt sort data..

Comment: I mean GROUP sorry, my query grouped messages with similar message_id together and displayed the first message but I want it to the last message. This is my problem.

Comment: @almasshaikh GROUP BY *does* sort data - but that's obviously not its primary purpose

Answer (score 0):

**Query:** SELECT * FROM message where id IN (SELECT max(id) FROM message where id IN(SELECT id from message group by message_id) group by message_id) ORDER BY id ASC

Here is table used to query:

```
id sender_id    receiver_id     message_id  message           time
1   2                 7              9        hi        2015-01-03 15:48:04
2   7                 2              9        hello     2015-01-03 14:50:53
3   4                 2              6        good      2015-01-03 14:50:53
4   2                 4              6        bad       2015-01-03 14:51:10
```